# js error, while running gulp -- import plugins from 'gulp-load-plugins'

Tags: javascript, gulp

```
import plugins  from 'gulp-load-plugins';
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Liftoff.handleArguments (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:116:3)
```

while runnig gulp babel from zurb 6. anyone got idea?

Comment: did you run npm install from command prompt?

Comment: yes - but now I found out there is no more gulp4.0 repository...
that cause an error during npm install...thx a lot

Comment: did it solves your problem? or there are more.?